# VSTO 2010 activate equation editor programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, ms-office, add-in

C#/.NET 3.5+

I'm trying to write a PowerPoint 2010 add-in that turns on (/off) the built-in equation editor, as if you had clicked the button on the *Insert* Ribbon tab, to get around a strangely lacking key binding. [The new key binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2010/04/08/using-shortcut-keys-to-call-a-function-in-an-office-add-in.aspx) is in place. Now I need to either fool PowerPoint into thinking I pressed a different key combination, which sounds neither right nor particularly easy, or manually activate the editor. Is there a `Some.Path.To.A.SetFancyEquationEditorEnabled(true);` I can hook into, or a different approach that achieves this?

**Edit 26/04:**
This block will emulate the supported shortcut combination but works unreliably (calling it twice in a row fails). I have had no luck emulating `Alt+=`, which does the same in the English version. I'm posting this because it's not really a solution

```
SendKeys.SendWait("%");
SendKeys.SendWait("N");
SendKeys.SendWait("3");
SendKeys.SendWait("I");
```

[MSDN: How to: Simulate Mouse and Keyboard Events in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx)